# Java Unreported Exception in ADT

Tags: java, exception

Okay for a class I had to build a queue ADT and use that ADT to create an application that does basic adding/subtracting. The problem is that when I try to invoke the queue's methods that have an exception linked to them I get " error: unreported exception FullCollectionException; must be caught or declared to be thrown".

Here is what my code looks like.

```
   public void insert(Object element) throws FullCollectionException
   {
       if(isFull())
          throw new FullCollectionException("Queue");
       else
       {
         queue[count] = element;
         count++;
       }
    }
```

The isFull method just does a simple comparison to see if the array has met its length. Then the class that uses it is as follows.

```
public class Stocks
{
   public static void main(String a[])
   {
       Queue q = new Queue();
       StackObject so = new StackObject();

       q.insert(10);
       q.insert(30);
   } 
 }
```

I tried several different things but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `FullCollectionException` is a child of `RuntimeException` (which is unchecked), you won't be able to do that. Try this:

```
try {
  q.insert(10);
  q.insert(30);
} catch (FullCollectionException fce) {
  // Handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that `main()` could potentially throw that exception, like this:

```
public static void main(String a[]) throws FullCollectionException
{
   Queue q = new Queue();
   StackObject so = new StackObject();

   q.insert(10);
   q.insert(30);
}
```

Or you could add a `catch` block instead, but you should only ever do that if you have an actual plan to recover from the exception. Otherwise, it's actually better to let your program fail rather than silently sweep problems under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly throw or catch the `FullCollectionException` in the main method.

PS: if you use an IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans to write your code, you will be prompted to add such exception handling statements.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I made the exceptions as part of my assignment and I just had them be a child of Exception instead of RuntimeException. Thanks for all your help :))